# Get VNC server to work on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: software-installation, remote-desktop

I'm running a Pi 4 with ubuntu 20.10 it's great but my VNC server wont install? It's in a unheated building so I will need a remote access solution.

Comment: So... What VNC server are we talking about here? There are more than one. When you say it won't install, what is actually happening when you try to install it?

Comment: I use real VNC it has a great ios app

Comment: Are you saying that you're using the RealVNC *server*? (You can use the RealVNC client to view *any* VNC server.) If you're using the RealVNC server, purge it and find a tutorial for x11vnc - it's easy to install and rock-solid stability, and it has the benefit of being able to be installed with `sudo apt install x11vnc`. Then, you just run the initial setup and make an edit to the config file and you're golden - and you can still use RealVNC Viewer just fine.